# Jenkins MultiJob - merging console output from child jobs into one output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins Multijob project (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin), with let's say 10 child jobs. Each of these jobs has console output that is essential for me to watch. Rather than open 10 tabs and jump between them to watch the output, is there a way I can funnel all the console output of each job into one? Can I perhaps send all this output to the console of the master/Multijob, instead of it simply listing [SUCCESS] or [FAILURE] of each of the child jobs?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and I found that post [Jenkins hierarchical jobs and jobs status aggregation](https://halyph.blogspot.com/2013/01/jenkins-hierarchical-jobs-and-jobs.html)

Base on that I did something similar to my multijob with only one level of phase jobs

```
import hudson.model.*
import com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.*;

void log(msg) {
  manager.listener.logger.println(msg)
}

threshold = Result.SUCCESS

void aggregate_results() {
    failed = false

    mainJob = manager.build.getProject().getName()
    job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(mainJob)

    log "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    log "Aggregated status report"
    log "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

    log("${mainJob}    #${manager.build.getNumber()} - ${manager.build.getResult()}")

    job.getLastBuild().getSubBuilds().each { subBuild->
      subJob = subBuild.getJobName() 
      subJobNumber = subBuild.getBuildNumber()
      job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(subBuild.getJobName())
      log "${subJob}   #${subJobNumber} - ${job.getLastCompletedBuild().getResult()}"
      log job.getLastCompletedBuild().getLog()
    }
}

try {
  aggregate_results()
} catch(Exception e) {
  log("ERROR: ${e.message}")
  log("ERROR: Failed Status report aggregation")
}
```